# Transform a vector of positive and negative values to sum up to 0

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, vectors, transformation

Is there a transformation that produces a vector with sum $0$?

There are positive and negative values and the transformation does not need to be preserve the weights.
E.g.: $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_1', x_2', x_3')$ s.t. $$\sum_{i=1}^3x_i' = 0$$

Comment: The simplest solution is the zero map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with centering where I subtract the mean from each $x_i$:
$$f(x) = x_i - \bar{x}, \text{ with }\ \bar{x} = \frac{1}{3} \sum_i^3 x_i$$

This way the absolute distances between the $x_i$ is preserved and the $x'_i$ add up to 0.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Intrigued, i started looking for a linear map,
$$
f
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1' \\ x_2' \\ x_3'
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Imposing that $x_1'+x_2'+x_3'=0$, we get that
$$(a_1+b_1+c_1)x_1+(a_2+b_2+c_2)x_2+(a_3+b_3+c_3)x_3=0$$
So one example of a linear map that produces vectors with sum of the component $0$, is the map given by the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{with} \quad
\begin{cases}
a_1+b_1+c_1=0\\
a_2+b_2+c_2=0\\
a_3+b_3+c_3=0
\end{cases}
$$
and i think you can produce infinitely many examples.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. This looks like the trivial solution that would always produce $x_i' = 0$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Philohippo there are non trivial solutions. E.g. try (a1,a2,a3) = (1,1,-2); (b1,b2,b3) = (-2,1,1); and (c1,c2,c3) = (1,-2,1). I did some experimenting and it sends non-trivial x to non-trivial x' which satisfy the condition that sum(x')=0.